# How to convert this arrow function to normal function expression to help me understand it better

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

How to convert this arrow function to normal function expression to help me understand it better?

```
export const updateDetails = data => dispatch => dispatch({
  type: ActionTypes.USER_UPDATE_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  data
});
```

i understand that the data is one of the function parameters but I don't understand what is the purpose of this part: "dispatch =>". Is it a parameter? of what exactly?

Comment: It's a curried function - the first one takes `data` and returns a second function that takes `dispatch`. The second function then runs `dispatch()` and uses `data` in the invocation.

Comment: The second argument of the arrow function is the return value of the function. In this case, you are returning another arrow function. So the "normal function expression" will be: `function updateDetails(data) {
 return function (dispatch) {
  return dispatch({
   type: ActionTypes.USER_UPDATE_DETAILS_REQUEST,,
   data,
  });
 };
}` (https://pastebin.com/GDhx474G)